How can I lazy compute at runtime some properties everytime the model/a field is updated?
I'm learning pydantic and I wish to understand the interaction between Python classes and their properties with the models of pydantic.
In particular I wish to define some instance variables that are calculated lazily at runtime after the model is created and everytime the model or a particular field is updated. Here a small play code snippet.
The question is: how can I code that everytime I change either the birthdate or the age (assuming one can compute the latter from the given value) and then re-evalute is_adult?
Can I achive this with just @propertied decorator of Python and @computed_field of Pyndatic or do I have to exploit the @model_validator decorator of Pyndatic to get this hook behaviour?
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator, field_validator, computed_field
from datetime import datetime


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    birthdate: Optional[datetime]
    _children_names: list[str] = []

    @computed_field
    @property
    def children_names(self) -> list[str]:
        return self._children_names
    
    @children_names.setter
    def children_names(self, values: list[str]):
        self._children_names += values

    @computed_field
    @property
    def is_adult(self) -> bool:
        return self.age >= 18

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def compute_age(cls, values):
        birthdate = values.birthdate
        values.age = datetime.today().year - birthdate.year
        return values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    person = {
        "name": "Luca",
        "birthdate": "1993-01-30",
    }
    p = Person.model_validate(person)


Well, I guess it's impossible to calculate birthdate from the age, so for your example I would use just a few computed fields:
class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    birthdate: datetime

    @computed_field
    @property
    def age(self) -> int:
        return datetime.today().year - self.birthdate.year

    @computed_field
    @property
    def is_adult(self) -> bool:
        return self.age >= 18

If you do have multiple dependent fields I would recommend to use the approach from this answer:
from dateutil import parser
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator, computed_field, ConfigDict
from datetime import datetime


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    birthdate: datetime
    age: int

    model_config = ConfigDict(validate_assignment=True)

    @computed_field
    @property
    def is_adult(self) -> bool:
        return self.age >= 18

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    def compute_age(cls, values: dict) -> dict:
        birthdate = values["birthdate"]

        if isinstance(birthdate, str):
            birthdate = parser.parse(birthdate)

        # Here you can compute either age based on birthday or vice versa if it were possible.
        # I will compute age just for example.
        values["age"] = datetime.today().year - birthdate.year

        return values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    person = Person.model_validate({
        "name": "Luca",
        "birthdate": "1993-01-30",
    })
    person.is_adult # True
    
    person.birthdate = datetime(2007, 1, 1)
    person.is_adult  # False
    
    person.birthdate = datetime(1981, 1, 1)
    person.is_adult  # True


model_validator along with validate_assignment=True property in the config is pretty good choice for implementing such logic.

In terms of readability I prefer to define properties all together in pyndatic style. Is it possible not to use properties decorator of python but to use just pyndatic solution/style?

The double properties was a type. I will edit the answer!

If I got your question correctly, yes, you can skip @property decorator as mentioned in the second code snippet in the docs

_children_names should never be None; it's initialized with an empty list. (Though it should be initialized with a factory, not the same default list for every instance.)

@chepner Good point

I edited the question to be more precise on my goal, if you wish to update your question and help me

@Luca Please check the updated answer. Hope this helps!
